# Why can I refer to UIKit classes after removing the import of UIKit.h?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, import, header-files

I've been watching a video that stated that `UIAlertView` works only if UIKit.h has been imported. However, if I comment out the import statement in the header file:

```
//#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

the alert still works when I add it to the implementation file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Please explain why this works? What is the true role of UIKit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIKit.h` is just the file where the classes etc. are defined.

Without it, the compiler wouldn't know what `UIAlertView` is.

However, in your case it probably works anyway, as the `#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>` is usually included in your project's prefix file, which is included by default in your sources.

Comment: That makes sense, but why is the #import <UIKit/UIKit.h> statement included header files. It seems redundant.

Comment: @user1209902: I guess it somewhat is, depending on how you use it. It's purely for convenience reasons; it can be easier to put an `#import` or various `#ifdef`s etc. in the prefix file rather than having to specify them in every other `.h` file in your project...

Answer (score 8):

It's because it's probably already declared in your `Prefix.pch` file, which looks something like this by default:

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#endif
```